# Seems like I'm missing a directive? System.Data.DataTableCollection does not contain a definition for 'First'

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dataset where I'm running a foreach loop on the rows...

```
foreach(var row in input.Tables.First().Rows)
{....
```

but I'm receiving this compilation error:

> Error 1   'System.Data.DataTableCollection' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTableCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It almost seems like I'm missing a directive but I'm using System.Linq and I also have System.Data.DataSetExtensions added as a reference.

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated. The project is set to .NET 4.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature for `First()` is:

```
public static TSource First<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source
)
```

so it has to be called on an `IEnumerable<T>`.

`DataTableCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

In order to use most Linq methods on it (and on other types that implement `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>`), you need to use `.Cast<T>()` or `.OfType<T>()`:

```
input.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().First().Rows
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `Cast` operation. `DataTableCollection` doesnt implement `IEnumerable<T>` so Linq doesn't apply any of the generic extension methods.

You can use `Cast` to make is a generic enumerable. like this:

```
foreach(var row in input.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().First().Rows) {..
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
input.Tables.OfType<DataTable>().First().Rows
```

Specifically tell it that it's of type `DataTable`.

Comment: I'm still receiving the same error :( After your revision, it seems to work. But why does it work when defining the type?

Comment: Because Tables is of type DataTableCollection which does not implement IEnumerable<T>.